# degraded iops and throughput on a linux machine in a cluster

Tags: linux, disk, aws, iostat

we have a linux-based cluster on AWS with 8 workers.

OS version (taken from /proc/version) is:

Linux version 5.4.0-1029-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-021) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 11:09:25 UTC 2020

worker id 5 was added recently, and the problem that we see is that during times of high disk util% due to a burst of writes into the workers, the disk mounted to that worker's data dir (/dev/nvme1n1p1) shows a degraded performance in terms of w/sec and wMB/sec, which are much lower on that worker compared to the other 7 workers (~40% less iops and throughput on that broker).

the data in this table was taken from running iostat -x on all the brokers, starting at the same time and ending after 3 hours during peak time. the cluster handles ~2M messages/sec.

another strange behavior is that broker id 7 has ~40% more iops and throughput during bursts of writes compared to the other brokers.

worker type is i3en.3xlarge with one nvme ssd 7.5TB.

**any idea as to what can cause such degraded performance in worker id 5 (or such a good performance on broker id 7)?**

this issue is causing the consumers from this cluster to lag during high writes because worker id 5 gets into high iowait, and in case some consumer reads gets into lag and performs reads from the disk then the iowait on worker id 5 climbs into ~70% and all consumers start to lag and also the producers get OOM due buffered messages that the broker doesn't accept.

[image: iops & throughput of all workers in the cluster (taken from iostat -x)]

Comment: only AWS can answer this for sure.  but some guesses/things to try: 1. are they all using the same fileystem type?  2. do they all have the same brand/model of nvme drive?  3.  have you tried trimming the nvme?

Comment: - they're all ext4 if that's what you mean in file system type. 
- how can I check the brand and model of the nvme?
- the nvme is trimmed to 6.9tb out of the available 7.5TB storage, if that's what you mean.

Comment: 1. Yeah, ext4 vs xfs or whatever is what i meant with fs type.  ext4 is fine. 2.  i don't know what info AWS exposes to VMs about the underlying hardware, but you might try looking at the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id/` 3. I mean using `fstrim` on your filesystems - the TRIM function tells the NVME SSD which blocks are no longer in use and can be properly erased and returned to the free block list.  It's much faster for an SSD to write a free block than have to read, erase, and re-write a block already in use.

Comment: Have you tried to update your Linux/Ubuntu version?